# Magento Session from external page (same domain)

Tags: php, magento, session, magento-1.7

I need to check that a user is registered and get your information, but all in a file within the same domain but outside the structure of Magento: /mymagento/islogged.php

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(); 

define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));

$sessionCustomer = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
if($sessionCustomer->isLoggedIn()) {
    $customer = $sessionCustomer->getCustomer();
    $telefono = $customer->getTelefonoMovil();
} else {
    header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}
```

But it does not work, can not find the session. I have reviewed the following threads:

- [Magento Session not working in external page (same domain)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567806/magento-session-not-working-in-external-page-same-domain)
- [Magento customer/session not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891761/magento-customer-session-not-working)
- [How do I create a Magento session outside of Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048180/how-do-i-create-a-magento-session-outside-of-magento)
- [How to access Magento user's session from outside Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098871/how-to-access-magento-users-session-from-outside-magento)
- [Checking for Magento login on external page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724334/checking-for-magento-login-on-external-page)
- [Get magento session variable in another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578318/get-magento-session-variable-in-another-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I did as follows:

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app(); 

// Define the path to the root of Magento installation.
define('ROOT', Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB));

// Obtain the general session and search for an item called 'customer_id'
$coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
if(isset($coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'])){
    $customerId = $coreSession['visitor_data']['customer_id'];
} else {
    header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load the user session.
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->loginById($customerId);
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

// We verified that created successfully (not required)
if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
    header('Location: '.ROOT.'customer/account/login/');
}

// Load customer
$customer = $customerSession->getCustomer();

// We get cell phone
$telefono = $customer->getTelefonoMovil();
```